# Как изменить данные в файле app.config c#

Tags: c#

Как изменить значение переменной timeout, которая храниться в файле app.config, так что бы изменился и сам файл? Вот мой код, в процессе работы программы ConfigurationManager выдает измененное значение, но после перезапуска опять стандартное. Visual Studio 2012, c#

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["timeout"].Value = resFromEnterCountForm.ToString();
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не можете сохранить app config, т. к. приложение устанавливается для всех пользователей (и содержит общий app.config), а выполняется от имени конкретного пользователя. Вам нужно писать данные в пользовательскую секцию.

Проще всего не идти через app.config, вручную, а использовать `Settings`. Для этого создайте в свойствах проекта `Settings`, и положите туда свойство в user scope:

[image: settings]

(заметьте, вы сразу получаете тип `int`, а не `string`).

Теперь ваш код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
var oldTimeout = settings.timeout;
settings.timeout = 2;
settings.Save();
```