# Запись в текстовый файл созданный в ресурcах

Tags: c#, .net, файлы, text, resources

Я создал в ресурсах текстовый файл . Как туда записать строку ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете писать в свои ресурсы. Дело в том, что ресурсы являются частью исполнимого файла, который находятся в недоступном по записи для текущего пользователя месте (`Program Files`). Даже если вы переместите файл в место, доступное для записи, всё равно он принадлежит бегущему приложению, и будет залочен.

Правильное, рекомендованное разработчиками место для записи своих данных — `Settings` или локальный файл в `%APPDATA%\<Имя вашего приложения>`.

Вот аналогичный вопрос: [Как изменить данные в файле app.config c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502621/10105).