# Проверить уровень прав пользователя для изменения содержимого файла

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli

Очень насущный вопрос. Моя программа требует запуска от имени администратора, что для большинства её пользователей в новинку.
2 вопроса: почему моя программа не может без определенного уровня прав пользователя изменять свои файлы конфигурации расположенные в одном каталоге с .exe? И как проверить уровень прав пользователя на изменение файла для того чтобы сообщить ему об этом?

Вопрос стал для меня камнем преткновения в связи с тем что в моей новой функции мне нужно однозначно быть уверенным что в файл внесутся новые записи ну или как минимум проверить заранее могут ли быть внесены данные изменения.

Answer (score 6):

Смотрите.

У Windows, как и у любой уважающей себя операционной системы, есть *разделение прав*. Пользователи делятся на нормальных и администраторов. У нормальных пользователей права есть лишь для записи в собственные каталоги, а вот для записи в каталог *Program Files*, *Windows* и т. п. нужны права администратора. Иначе систему могла бы разрушить любая программа, запущенная глупым пользователем. (А так для того, чтобы реально что-то сломать, ей нужны администраторские права.)

Из этого следует то, что *изменяемые* конфигурационные файлы **нельзя** хранить в каталоге с программой. Хуже того, изменяемые конфигурационные файлы у вас должны храниться для каждого из пользователей отдельно, потому что пользователь `A` не имеет прав доступа к файлам пользователя `B`, и тем более не имеет прав на каталог с программой.

Предписанное место для хранения изменяемой конфигурации — каталог `%APPDATA%\<имя программы>`. Это место гарантированно доступно на чтение/запись для каждого пользователя.

---

Проще всего не строить велосипед, а воспользоваться встроенным классом `Settings`. Он делит данные на отдельных пользователей и хранит их в `%APPDATA%` самостоятельно, без вашего вмешательства. Про `Settings` можно почитать здесь:

- [Ответ на аналогичную тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502621/10105) с картинками и примерами кода
- [Документация Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)

---

**Обновление**

Окей, если вам реально нужно модифицировать данные, которые лежат в каталоге `%PROGRAMFILES%`, то вам таки придётся проверить, запущена ли ваша программа с правами администратора. Вы можете это выяснить при помощи вот такого кода:

```
bool isAdmin = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
        .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

Другой путь — потребовать административные права в манифесте. Для этого нужно для начала добавить манифест, если у вас он ещё не добавлен (правая кнопка мыши по проекту → Add → New Item → Application Manifest File), и в секции `<requestedPrivileges ...>` добавить

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Параметр `uiAccess="false"` означает, что вашей программе не нужно посылать ввод окнам *других* приложений (что скорее всего так и есть). [Смотрите комментарий @PetSerAl, там больше подробностей по теме.]

Comment: второй вопрос (вопрос темы) остается, моя программа модифицирует файлы игры которая лежит скорее всего не в %APPDATA%\<имя программы>

Comment: @Smirnov: Ну, этого она делать не должна. Все файлы, которые необходимо модифицировать, должны лежать в доступном текущему юзеру для записи месте.

Comment: с точки зрения системы - не должна; с точки зрения пользователя - должна, так как программа создана для установки модификаций на игру в 1 клик, выхода нет, нужно знать внесла ли она изменения в игру или нет для того чтобы не повредить её окончательно последующими действиями

Comment: @Smirnov: Дописал ответ, читайте.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, однако есть вопросик. Вот игра, файлы которой я модифицирую, не требует запуска от имени администратора для того чтобы в каталоге %PROGRAMFILES% создавыать свои логи (которые при чистой установке отсутствуют) и сейвы (игра старая и не знает про "Мои документы"). Почему так? Мне нужен запуск от имени администратора, а ей нет?

Comment: Разве `uiAccess="false"` означает *не сможет показывать UI*? Например `netplwiz.exe` имеет в манифесте `level="requireAdministrator"` и `uiAccess="false"` и при этом прекрасно справляется с задачей отображения UI.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Тьфу, и правда. Что-то я туплю. Сейчас подправлю ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: @Smirnov: Я что-то нагородил с `uiAccess="false"`, извиняюсь. Подправил ответ.

Comment: @Smirnov: Насчёт того, что игра не требует запуска от имени админа, странно. Думаю, что в реальности она туда ничего не пишет, а с ней происходит _автовиртуализация каталогов_ (об этом смотрите [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681)). Возможно, реальные данные хранятся в `%LOCAL­APP­DATA%\Virtual­Store`.

Comment: @VladD Не думаю, что вы правы на счёт `uiAccess="false"`. На сколько я понимаю, программа всегда может взаимодействовать с окнами приложений равного или более низкого уровня целостности (integrity level), а `uiAccess="true"` используется для программ специальных возможностей, таких как `osk.exe`, `narrator.exe` или `magnify.exe`, и позволяет им взаимодействовать с окнами приложений более высокого уровня целостности.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Я ориентировался на текст [отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx): «False //
The application does not need to drive input to the user interface of another window on the desktop. Applications that are not providing accessibility should set this flag to false. Applications that are required to drive input to other windows on the desktop (on-screen keyboard, for example) should set this value to true.» Но скорее всего вы правы, да. // Исправил текст снова.