# Как правильно вывести сохраненную переменную?

Tags: c#

Имею участок кода, в котором сохраняю нужную мне переменную в файл:

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("result.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(a);
        sw.Close();

    }
```

Как мне теперь при следующем запуске программы обратиться к записанной переменной, чтобы вывести ее скажем, в текстбокс?

```
//    textbox1.text=?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
try
{
    a = File.ReadLines("result.txt").First();
}
catch (IOException)
{
}
```

Это для строковой переменной `a`, для например целочисленной нужно ещё `int.Parse`.

---

Два замечания. Во-первых, писать в файл проще через `File.WriteAllText("result.txt", а)`. А во-вторых, для хранения переменных между запусками программы имеет смысл использовать [`Settings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet) (пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502621/10105)).

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает.

Comment: @Georg96: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!